# How to force error or stoppage in SSIS data flow during the debugging process?

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

The problem is: i make left join for two tables and then i need to load whole data to another table but only if every row from first table has match in second one, so, to cut it short, there is no NULLs in one exact column.
If there is at least one null i want to fail my data flow so it'll not load any data to final table and then send an email with the error by executing sql task.

[image]

After many tries i can only make errors if there is nulls but this error are not fatal. How can i raise fatal error not using smth stupid like data conversion which can't be done? I was trying to make breakpoint after some variable is changed but was defeated by ssis(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the Data Flow loads data to Table1. The Execute SQL Task uses Table1 to populate Table2.

The business rule is that the Execute SQL Task should *only* fire if a column from the previous data load had no NULLs.

The lazy way to handle this, is to put the logic in the query itself. Something like the following and yes, there are ways to optimize this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE MyColumn IS NOT NULL)
```

To make this happen only in SSIS,

- Add a Variable to the Package called NullRowCount and initialize it to zero.
- In the Data flow, add a Multicast between the Join and the Destination. Route one path to the destination
- In the Data flow, connect a Conditional Split to a new path from the Multicast. Configure the Conditional Split to have have an Output Name of "No Data" and use an expression like IsNull([MyColumn]). That's a boolean, yes/no.
- In the Data flow, add a Row Count transformation to the Conditional Split and attach it to the "No Data" pipe (the Default pipe will contain rows that have values in MyColumn). Use @[User::NullRowCount] in the Row Count transformation.
- Finally, double click the precedent constraint you have between the Data Flow and the Execute SQL Task. Make it back to an On Success constraint and then change the evaluation option from `Constraint` to `Constraint and Expression`. Here, we'll use an expression of `@[User::NullRowCount] == 0`

In plain English, we are going to have the data flow count how many rows in our set have a NULL in `MyColumn`. The Precedent Constraint will allow/disallow the Execute SQL Task to run and the criteria we specify are that the data flow had to run successfully and the count of rows with NULL in it is zero.

If say you wanted to have an action when the count is non-zero (send email or other alert), then you would add another Task and configure it with Expression and Constraint but now use an expression of `@[User::NullRowCount] > 0`

Based on the comment

> may be i can stop it (force an error) inside the data flow before loading data in data source? because this sql text sends an email, so i want all etl process to be done in one data flow

No, not really. Assuming you changed out the Row Count in the above with a Script Task that explicitly raises an error or a Derived Column Task that forces a divide by zero - either of those would interrupt a data flow, *but* you don't know whether it was the first row of the data flow that caused the exception or the one billionth. In the later case, the data has already flowed into the destination (unless you have the commit size of 0 which can lead to other issues) and you have partially loaded data.

Ultimately, you need to preprocess your data to identify if there's data that does not conform to expectation. I would make the above changes - count if you have any bad data but instead of landing data into a table, land it into a [Raw File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/raw-file-destination?view=sql-server-ver15). A raw file is a compact binary of the data so yes, you'll pay disk IO penalty but it will save you reprocessing the data if it's valid.

Then you add a new Data Flow Task that only works when you have a zero null count, using the precedent constraint approach described above. This new data flow is just Raw File Source to "original destination." Now you'll get a clean separation of data landing in your table only if pristine and not have to worry about partial loads.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome. To be honest i add Derived Column Task that forces a divide by zero because i have a few transformation in my real case before loading. It is weird that ssis has no usual ways to force an error, you can't even divide by zero, i was have to divide by my column*0